# installing mongodb on ubuntu 22

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I am trying to install mongodb (5 and then 4.4) on ubuntu22, but appearently my cpu does not support some instructions. any versions i installed resulted in core-dump error and illegal instruction error. i tried to install it using tar.gz but did not work either.
this is my cpu info:

```
Architecture:            x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:         39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                  2
  On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
Vendor ID:               GenuineIntel
  Model name:            Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU G3260 @ 3.30GHz
    CPU family:          6
    Model:               60
    Thread(s) per core:  1
    Core(s) per socket:  2
    Socket(s):           1
    Stepping:            3
    CPU max MHz:         3300.0000
    CPU min MHz:         800.0000
    BogoMIPS:            6585.15
    Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mc
                         a cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss 
                         ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arc
                         h_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc 
                         cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vm
                         x est tm2 ssse3 sdbg cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 
                         movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave rdrand lahf_lm ab
                         m cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb sti
                         bp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbas
                         e tsc_adjust erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm arat pln pts 
                         md_clear flush_l1d
Virtualization features: 
  Virtualization:        VT-x
Caches (sum of all):     
  L1d:                   64 KiB (2 instances)
  L1i:                   64 KiB (2 instances)
  L2:                    512 KiB (2 instances)
  L3:                    3 MiB (1 instance)
NUMA:                    
  NUMA node(s):          1
  NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0,1
Vulnerabilities:         
  Itlb multihit:         KVM: Mitigation: VMX disabled
  L1tf:                  Mitigation; PTE Inversion; VMX conditional cache flushe
                         s, SMT disabled
  Mds:                   Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT disabled
  Meltdown:              Mitigation; PTI
  Mmio stale data:       Not affected
  Spec store bypass:     Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl
                          and seccomp
  Spectre v1:            Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer
                          sanitization
  Spectre v2:            Mitigation; Retpolines, IBPB conditional, IBRS_FW, STIB
                         P disabled, RSB filling
  Srbds:                 Mitigation; Microcode
  Tsx async abort:       Not affected
```

my question is: beside changing my cpu is there any way to install mongodb on ubuntu?

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodb-5-0-cpu-intel-g4650-compatibility/116610 check this

Comment: thanks, i installed docker and used mongo:4 image. it works fine for now